# insert vs emplace vs operator[] in c++ map

Tags: c++, dictionary, insert, operators, emplace

I'm using maps for the first time and I realized that there are many ways to insert an element. You can use `emplace()`, `operator[]` or `insert()`, plus variants like using `value_type` or `make_pair`. While there is a lot of information about all of them and questions about particular cases, I still can't understand the big picture.
So, my two questions are:

1. What is the advantage of each one of them over the others?
2. Was there any need for adding emplace to the standard? Is there anything that wasn't possible before without it?

Comment: Emplacement semantics allow explicit conversions and direct initialization.

Comment: Now `operator[]` is based on `try_emplace`. It may be worth mentioning `insert_or_assign` as well.

Comment: @FrankHB if you (or someone else) adds an up-to-date answer, I could change the accepted one.

Answer (score 348, accepted):

In the particular case of a map, the old options were only two: `operator[]` and `insert` (different flavors of `insert`). So, I will start explaining those.

The `operator[]` is a *find-or-add* operator. It will try to find an element with the given key inside the map, and if it exists, it will return a reference to the stored value. If it does not, it will create a new element inserted in place with default initialization and return a reference to it.

The `insert` function (in the single element flavor) takes a `value_type` (`std::pair<const Key,Value>`), it uses the key (`first` member) and tries to insert it. Because `std::map` does not allow for duplicates if there is an existing element it will not insert anything.

The first difference between the two is that `operator[]` needs to be able to construct a default initialized *value*, and it is thus unusable for value types that cannot be default initialized. The second difference between the two is what happens when there is already an element with the given key. The `insert` function will not modify the state of the map, but instead return an iterator to the element (and a `false` indicating that it was not inserted).

```cpp
// assume m is std::map<int,int> already has an element with key 5 and value 0
m[5] = 10;                      // postcondition: m[5] == 10
m.insert(std::make_pair(5,15)); // m[5] is still 10
```

In the case of `insert`, the argument is an object of `value_type`, which can be created in different ways. You can directly construct it with the appropriate type or pass any object from which the `value_type` can be constructed, which is where `std::make_pair` comes into play, as it allows for simple creation of `std::pair` objects, although it is probably not what you want...

The net effect of the following calls is *similar*:

```cpp
K t; V u;
std::map<K,V> m;           // std::map<K,V>::value_type is std::pair<const K,V>
    
m.insert( std::pair<const K,V>(t,u) );      // 1
m.insert( std::map<K,V>::value_type(t,u) ); // 2
m.insert( std::make_pair(t,u) );            // 3
```

But they are not really the same... [1] and [2] are actually equivalent. In both cases the code creates a temporary object of the same type (`std::pair<const K,V>`) and passes it to the `insert` function. The `insert` function will create the appropriate node in the binary search tree and then copy the `value_type` part from the argument to the node. The advantage of using `value_type` is that, well, `value_type` always *matches* `value_type`, you cannot mistype the type of the `std::pair` arguments!

The difference is in [3]. The function `std::make_pair` is a template function that will create a `std::pair`. The signature is:

```cpp
template <typename T, typename U>
std::pair<T,U> make_pair(T const & t, U const & u );
```

I have intentionally not provided the template arguments to `std::make_pair`, as that is the common usage. And the implication is that the template arguments are deduced from the call, in this case to be `T==K,U==V`, so the call to `std::make_pair` will return a `std::pair<K,V>` (note the missing `const`). The signature requires `value_type` that is *close* but not the same as the returned value from the call to `std::make_pair`. Because it is close enough, it will create a temporary of the correct type and copy initialize it. That will in turn be copied to the node, creating a total of two copies.

This can be fixed by providing the template arguments:

```cpp
m.insert( std::make_pair<const K,V>(t,u) );  // 4
```

But, that is still error prone in the same way that explicitly typing the type is in case [1].

Up to this point, we have different ways of calling `insert` that require the creation of the `value_type` externally and the copy of that object into the container. Alternatively you can use `operator[]` if the type is *default constructible* and *assignable* (intentionally focusing only in `m[k]=v`), and it requires the default initialization of one object and the *copy* of the value into that object.

In C++11, with variadic templates and perfect forwarding there is a new way of adding elements into a container by means of *emplacing* (creating in place). The `emplace` functions in the different containers do basically the same thing: instead of getting a *source* from which to *copy* into the container, the function takes the parameters that will be forwarded to the constructor of the object stored in the container.

```cpp
m.emplace(t,u);               // 5
```

In [5], the `std::pair<const K, V>` is not created and passed to `emplace`, but rather references to the `t` and `u` object are passed to `emplace` that forwards them to the constructor of the `value_type` subobject inside the data structure. In this case *no* copies of the `std::pair<const K,V>` are done at all, which is the advantage of `emplace` over the C++03 alternatives. As in the case of `insert` it will not override the value in the map.

---

An interesting question that I had not thought about is how `emplace` can actually be implemented for a map, and that is not a simple problem in the general case.

Comment: This is hinted in the answer, but map[]=val will overwrite the previous value if one exists.

Comment: a more interesting question in my sense, is that it serves little purpose. Because you save the pair copy, which is good because no pair copy means no `mapped_type` isntance copy. What we want, is emplace the construction of the `mapped_type` in the pair, and emplace the pair construction in the map. Therefore, the `std::pair::emplace` function, and its forwarding support in `map::emplace` are both missing. In its current form, you still have to give a constructed mapped_type to the pair constructor which will copy it, once. its better than twice, but still no good.

Comment: actually I amend that comment, in C++11 there is a template pair constructor that serves the exact same purpose than emplace in the case of 1 argument construction. and some weird piecewise construct, as they call it, using tuples to forward arguments, so we can still have perfect forwarding it seems.

Comment: Looks like there is a performance bug of insert in unordered_map and map: [link](http://www.forwardscattering.org/post/37)

Comment: @Deqing: Nothing new, that's been known for ages in most implementations, but it is not a bug in the standard. Some implementations need to pay the cost, others are just not being smart enough about how to do it because it complicates the code sufficiently to do the right thing, and it does not really take all the cost away. A common solution for some cases is using `operator[]` if the Value's value-initialized is not a valid entry in the map (say `map<int, shared_ptr<T>>` in most cases an empty `shared_ptr` is not a valid value)

Comment: Might be nice to update this with info on `insert_or_assign` and `try_emplace` (both from C++17), which help fill some gaps in functionality from the existing methods.

Answer (score 18):

Emplace: Takes advantage of the rvalue reference to use the actual objects that you have already created.  This means that no copy or move constructor is called, good for LARGE objects! O(log(N)) time.

Insert: Has overloads for standard lvalue reference and rvalue reference, as well as iterators to lists of elements to insert, and "hints" as to the position an element belongs.  The use of a "hint" iterator can bring the time insertion takes down to contant time, otherwise it is O(log(N)) time.

Operator[]: Checks to see if the object exists, and if it does, modifies the reference to this object, otherwise uses the provided key and value to call make_pair on the two objects, and then does the same work as the insert function.  This is O(log(N)) time.

make_pair: Does little more than make a pair.

There was no "need" for adding emplace to the standard.  In c++11 I believe the && type of reference was added.  This removed the necessity for move semantics, and allowed optimization of some specific type of memory management.  In particular, the rvalue reference.  The overloaded insert(value_type &&) operator does not take advantage of the in_place semantics, and is therefore much less efficient.  While it provides the capability of dealing with rvalue references, it ignores their key purpose, which is in place construction of objects.

Comment: "_There was no "need" for adding emplace to the standard."_ This is patently false. `emplace()` is simply the only way to insert an element that cannot be copied or moved. (& yes, perhaps, to most efficiently insert one whose copy and move constructors cost a lot more than construction, if such a thing exists) It also seems you got the idea wrong: it's not about "_[taking] advantage of the rvalue reference to use the actual objects that you have already created_"; no object is created yet, & you forward the `map` the arguments **it** needs to create it inside itself. You don't make the object.

Comment: @underscore_d Fixed in edit.

Comment: @Ben_LCDB Thanks for taking the time to try! But I don't agree with edits that substantially change the meaning of the post. If the author wants to fix their post, they can. I don't think it's other members' place to 'fix' it for them by changing the sentiment. Otherwise no one would ever have time to post good answers, as they'd be spending it 'fixing' all the bad ones...

Comment: Is it the change of order in the section that made you think it was substantially ? Nevermind !

Answer (score 17):

The main difference is in what constructors are/aren't called. As [stated at cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/emplace): "**Careful** use of `emplace` allows [...] avoiding unnecessary copy or move operations." This is best explained by an example.

Say you're in `main()` adding `Foo` objects to a `set<Foo>` object, where `Foo` has copy/move constructors and a constructor `Foo(int)`. Then the main "big picture" difference is that:

- `emplace(42)` - which calls [`set::emplace(int && args)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/emplace) - *forwards* the given (length 1) list of arguments to a `Foo` constructor somewhere in the definition/body of the `set::emplace` method (e.g. the argument `42` is forwarded to a call like `Foo(42)` somewhere in the `std::emplace` method's code). Importantly: NO `Foo` copy or move constructor is called.
- `insert(42)` - which calls [`set::insert(Foo && ins_arg)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/insert) - needs a `Foo` object as input but is given the `int` `42` instead, so it: (1) first creates the (temporary) `Foo` object `Foo(42)` to use as `insert`'s argument. Then (2) somewhere in the definition of the `set::insert` method, this `Foo` object (in `ins_arg`) is used as an argument to a `Foo` copy or move constructor call (e.g. a call like `Foo(ins_arg)` is made). Finally, (3) the temporary `Foo` object from (1) is destroyed once `insert` is finished executing.

The code below shows the "big picture idea" of how `insert()` differs from `emplace()` by tracking every constructor call and telling you info about them as they happen. Comparing the output to the code will make the difference between `insert()` and `emplace()` clear.

The code is easy but a little long so to save time, I recommend you read the summary and then take a *quick* look through the code (this should be enough understand the code and its output).

**Summary of code**:

- **The `Foo` class**: uses `static int foo_counter` to keep track of the total number of `Foo` objects that have been constructed (or moved, copied, etc.) thus far. Each `Foo` object stores the (unique) value of `foo_counter` at the time of its creation in its local variable `val`. The unique object with `val` == `8` is called "`foo8`" or "`Foo` 8" (ditto for `1`, `2`, etc.). Every constructor/destructor call prints info about the call (e.g. calling `Foo(11)` will output "`Foo(int) with val: 11`").
- **`main()`'s body**: `insert()`s and `emplace()`s `Foo` objects into an `unordered_map<Foo,int>` object `umap` with calls such as "`umap.emplace(Foo(11), 0);`" and "`umap.insert({12, 0})`" (`0` is just some arbitrary `int`, it can be any value). Every line of code is printed to `cout` before it is executed.

## Code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <utility>
using namespace std;

//Foo simply outputs what constructor is called with what value.
struct Foo {
  static int foo_counter; //Track how many Foo objects have been created.
  int val; //This Foo object was the val-th Foo object to be created.
  Foo() { val = foo_counter++;
    cout << "Foo() with val:                " << val << '\n';
  }
  Foo(int value) : val(value) { foo_counter++;
    cout << "Foo(int) with val:             " << val << '\n';
  }
  Foo(Foo& f2) { val = foo_counter++;
    cout << "Foo(Foo &) with val:           " << val
         << " \tcreated from:      \t" << f2.val << '\n';
  }
  Foo(const Foo& f2) { val = foo_counter++;
    cout << "Foo(const Foo &) with val:     " << val
         << " \tcreated from:      \t" << f2.val << '\n';
  }
  Foo(Foo&& f2) { val = foo_counter++;
    cout << "Foo(Foo&&) moving:             " << f2.val
         << " \tand changing it to:\t" << val << '\n';
  }
  ~Foo() { cout << "~Foo() destroying:             " << val << '\n'; }
  Foo& operator=(const Foo& rhs) {
    cout << "Foo& operator=(const Foo& rhs) with rhs.val: " << rhs.val
         << " \tcalled with lhs.val = \t" << val
         << " \tChanging lhs.val to: \t" << rhs.val << '\n';
    val = rhs.val; return *this;
  }
  bool operator==(const Foo &rhs) const { return val == rhs.val; }
  bool operator<(const Foo &rhs)  const { return val <  rhs.val; }
};
int Foo::foo_counter = 0;

//Create a hash function for Foo in order to use Foo with unordered_map
template<> struct std::hash<Foo> {
   size_t operator()(const Foo &f) const { return hash<int>{}(f.val); }
};

int main() {
    unordered_map<Foo, int> umap;
    int d; //Some int that will be umap's value. It is not important.

    //Print the statement to be executed and then execute it.

    cout << "\nFoo foo0, foo1, foo2, foo3;\n";
    Foo foo0, foo1, foo2, foo3;

    cout << "\numap.insert(pair<Foo, int>(foo0, d))\n";
    umap.insert(pair<Foo, int>(foo0, d));
    //Side note: equivalent to: umap.insert(make_pair(foo0, d));

    cout << "\numap.insert(move(pair<Foo, int>(foo1, d)))\n";
    umap.insert(move(pair<Foo, int>(foo1, d)));
    //Side note: equiv. to: umap.insert(make_pair(foo1, d));
    
    cout << "\npair<Foo, int> pair(foo2, d)\n";
    pair<Foo, int> pair(foo2, d);

    cout << "\numap.insert(pair)\n";
    umap.insert(pair);

    cout << "\numap.emplace(foo3, d)\n";
    umap.emplace(foo3, d);
    
    cout << "\numap.emplace(11, d)\n";
    umap.emplace(11, d);

    cout << "\numap.insert({12, d})\n";
    umap.insert({12, d});

    cout.flush();
}
```

## Output

```
Foo foo0, foo1, foo2, foo3;
Foo() with val:                0
Foo() with val:                1
Foo() with val:                2
Foo() with val:                3

umap.insert(pair<Foo, int>(foo0, d))
Foo(Foo &) with val:           4    created from:       0
Foo(Foo&&) moving:             4    and changing it to: 5
~Foo() destroying:             4

umap.insert(move(pair<Foo, int>(foo1, d)))
Foo(Foo &) with val:           6    created from:       1
Foo(Foo&&) moving:             6    and changing it to: 7
~Foo() destroying:             6

pair<Foo, int> pair(foo2, d)
Foo(Foo &) with val:           8    created from:       2

umap.insert(pair)
Foo(const Foo &) with val:     9    created from:       8

umap.emplace(foo3, d)
Foo(Foo &) with val:           10   created from:       3

umap.emplace(11, d)
Foo(int) with val:             11

umap.insert({12, d})
Foo(int) with val:             12
Foo(const Foo &) with val:     13   created from:       12
~Foo() destroying:             12

~Foo() destroying:             8
~Foo() destroying:             3
~Foo() destroying:             2
~Foo() destroying:             1
~Foo() destroying:             0
~Foo() destroying:             13
~Foo() destroying:             11
~Foo() destroying:             5
~Foo() destroying:             10
~Foo() destroying:             7
~Foo() destroying:             9
```

## The BIG picture

The main "big picture" difference between `insert()` and `emplace()` is:

> Whereas using `insert()` *almost***†** *always* requires the construction or pre-existence of some `Foo` object in `main()`'s scope (followed by a copy or move), if using `emplace()` then any call to a `Foo` constructor is done entirely internally in the `unordered_map` (i.e. inside the scope of the `emplace()` method's definition). The argument(s) for the key that you pass to `emplace()` are directly forwarded to a `Foo` constructor call within `unordered_map::emplace()`'s definition (optional additional details: where this newly constructed object is immediately incorporated into one of `unordered_map`'s member variables so that no destructor is called when execution leaves `emplace()` and no move or copy constructors are called).

**†** The reason for the "*almost*" in "*almost always*" above is because one overload of `insert()` is actually *equivalent to* `emplace()`. As described [in this cppreference.com page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/insert), the overload `template<class P> pair<iterator, bool> insert(P&& value)` (which is overload (2) of `insert()` on that page) is equivalent to `emplace(forward<P>(value))`. Since we're interested in differences, I'm going to ignore this overload and not mention this particular technicality again.

## Stepping through the code

I will now go through the code and its output in detail.

1. First, notice that an `unordered_map` always internally stores `Foo` objects (and not, say, `Foo *`s) as keys, which are all destroyed when the `unordered_map` is destroyed. Here, the `unordered_map`'s internal keys were foos 13, 11, 5, 10, 7, and 9.

- So technically, our `unordered_map` actually stores `pair<const Foo, int>` objects, which in turn store the `Foo` objects. But to understand the "big picture idea" of how `emplace()` differs from `insert()` (see highlighted box above), it's okay to *temporarily* imagine this `pair` object as being entirely passive. Once you understand this "big picture idea," it's important to then back up and understand how the use of this intermediary `pair` object by `unordered_map` introduces subtle, but important, technicalities.

2. `insert()`ing each of `foo0`, `foo1`, and `foo2` required 2 calls to one of `Foo`'s copy/move constructors and 2 calls to `Foo`'s destructor (as I now describe):

   - `insert()`ing each of `foo0` and `foo1` created a temporary object (`foo4` and `foo6`, respectively) whose destructor was then immediately called after the insertion completed. In addition, the `unordered_map`'s internal `Foo`s (which are `foo`s 5 and 7) also had their destructors called when the `unordered_map` was destroyed once execution reached the end of `main()`.
   - To `insert()` `foo2`, we instead first explicitly created a non-temporary pair object (called `pair`), which called `Foo`'s copy constructor on `foo2` (creating `foo8` as an internal member of `pair`). We then `insert()`ed this pair, which resulted in `unordered_map` calling the copy constructor again (on `foo8`) to create its own internal copy (`foo9`). As with `foo`s 0 and 1, the end result was two destructor calls for this `insert()`ion with the only difference being that `foo8`'s destructor was called only when we reached the end of `main()` rather than being called immediately after `insert()` finished.
3. `emplace()`ing `foo3` resulted in only 1 copy/move constructor call (creating `foo10` internally in the `unordered_map` ) and only 1 call to `Foo`'s destructor. The reason why calling `umap.emplace(foo3, d)` called `Foo`'s non-const copy constructor is the following: Since we're using `emplace()`, the compiler knows that `foo3` (a non-const `Foo` object) is meant to be an argument to some `Foo` constructor. In this case, the most fitting `Foo` constructor is the non-const copy constructor `Foo(Foo& f2)`. This is why `umap.emplace(foo3, d)` called a copy constructor while `umap.emplace(11, d)` did not.
4. For `foo11`, we directly passed the integer 11 to `emplace(11, d)` so that `unordered_map` would call the `Foo(int)` constructor while execution is within its `emplace()` method. Unlike in (2) and (3), we didn't even need some pre-exiting `foo` object to do this. Importantly, notice that only 1 call to a `Foo` constructor occurred (which created `foo11`).
5. We then directly passed the integer 12 to `insert({12, d})`. Unlike with `emplace(11, d)` (which recall resulted in only 1 call to a `Foo` constructor), this call to `insert({12, d})` resulted in two calls to `Foo`'s constructor (creating `foo12` and `foo13`).

---

## Epilogue

Where to go from here?

a. Play around with the above source code and study documentation for `insert()` (e.g. [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/insert)) and `emplace()` (e.g. [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/emplace)) that's found online. If you're using an IDE such as eclipse or NetBeans then you can easily get your IDE to tell you which overload of `insert()` or `emplace()` is being called (in eclipse, just keep your mouse's cursor steady over the function call for a second). Here's some more code to try out:

```
cout << "\numap.insert({{" << Foo::foo_counter << ", d}})\n";
umap.insert({{Foo::foo_counter, d}});
//but umap.emplace({{Foo::foo_counter, d}}); results in a compile error!

cout << "\numap.insert(pair<const Foo, int>({" << Foo::foo_counter << ", d}))\n";
umap.insert(pair<const Foo, int>({Foo::foo_counter, d}));
//The above uses Foo(int) and then Foo(const Foo &), as expected. but the
// below call uses Foo(int) and the move constructor Foo(Foo&&). 
//Do you see why?
cout << "\numap.insert(pair<Foo, int>({" << Foo::foo_counter << ", d}))\n";
umap.insert(pair<Foo, int>({Foo::foo_counter, d}));
//Not only that, but even more interesting is how the call below uses all 
// three of Foo(int) and the Foo(Foo&&) move and Foo(const Foo &) copy 
// constructors, despite the below call's only difference from the call above 
// being the additional { }.
cout << "\numap.insert({pair<Foo, int>({" << Foo::foo_counter << ", d})})\n";
umap.insert({pair<Foo, int>({Foo::foo_counter, d})});


//Pay close attention to the subtle difference in the effects of the next 
// two calls.
int cur_foo_counter = Foo::foo_counter;
cout << "\numap.insert({{cur_foo_counter, d}, {cur_foo_counter+1, d}}) where " 
  << "cur_foo_counter = " << cur_foo_counter << "\n";
umap.insert({{cur_foo_counter, d}, {cur_foo_counter+1, d}});

cout << "\numap.insert({{Foo::foo_counter, d}, {Foo::foo_counter+1, d}}) where "
  << "Foo::foo_counter = " << Foo::foo_counter << "\n";
umap.insert({{Foo::foo_counter, d}, {Foo::foo_counter+1, d}});


//umap.insert(initializer_list<pair<Foo, int>>({{Foo::foo_counter, d}}));
//The call below works fine, but the commented out line above gives a 
// compiler error. It's instructive to find out why. The two calls
// differ by a "const".
cout << "\numap.insert(initializer_list<pair<const Foo, int>>({{" << Foo::foo_counter << ", d}}))\n";
umap.insert(initializer_list<pair<const Foo, int>>({{Foo::foo_counter, d}}));
```

You'll soon see that which overload of the `pair` constructor (see [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/pair)) ends up being used by `unordered_map` can have an important effect on how many objects are copied, moved, created, and/or destroyed as well as when this all occurs.

b. See what happens when you use some other container class (e.g. `set` or `unordered_multiset`) instead of `unordered_map`.

c. Now use a `Goo` object (just a renamed copy of `Foo`) instead of an `int` as the range type in an `unordered_map` (i.e. use `unordered_map<Foo, Goo>` instead of `unordered_map<Foo, int>`) and see how many and which `Goo` constructors are called. (Spoiler: there is an effect but it isn't very dramatic.)

Comment: I believe its worth mentioning, say if the `Foo(int)` is changed to something like `Foo(int, int)` where there are multiple arguments on constructor, then to achieve something similar to `umap.emplace(11, d)`, we can use `std::piecewise_construct` and `std::forward_as_tuple`. So the statement would be `umap.emplace(std::piecewise_construct, std::forward_as_tuple(11, 12), std::forward_as_tuple(d)); `

Answer (score 12):

Apart from the optimisation opportunities and the simpler syntax, an important distinction between insertion and emplacement is that the latter allows *explicit* conversions. (This is across the entire standard library, not just for maps.)

Here's an example to demonstrate:

```
#include <vector>

struct foo
{
    explicit foo(int);
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<foo> v;

    v.emplace(v.end(), 10);      // Works
    //v.insert(v.end(), 10);     // Error, not explicit
    v.insert(v.end(), foo(10));  // Also works
}
```

This is admittedly a very specific detail, but when you're dealing with chains of user-defined conversions, it's worth keeping this in mind.

Comment: Imagine that foo required two ints in its ctor rather than one.

Would you be able to use this call?

`v.emplace(v.end(), 10, 10);`

...or would you now need to use:

`v.emplace(v.end(), foo(10, 10) );`

?

Comment: I don't have access to a compiler right now, but I will assume that this means that both versions will work.

Almost all examples you see for `emplace` make use of a class that takes a single parameter. IMO it would actually make the nature of emplace's variadic syntax a good deal more clear if multiple parameters were used in examples.

Answer (score 1):

There is an additional issue that hasn't been discussed yet in the other answers, and it applies for `std::map` as well as for `std::unordered_map`, `std::set`, and `std::unordered_set`:

- `insert` works with a key object, which implies it **does not need to allocate a node** if the key is already present in the container.
- `emplace` needs to construct the key first, which, generally, **requires allocating a node** each time it is called.

From this perspective, `emplace` may be less efficient than `insert` if the key is already present in the container. (This may be significant for instance in multithreaded applications with thread-local dictionaries, where allocations need to be synchronized.)

Live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/ornYcTqW9. Note that with **libstdc++**, `emplace` allocates 10 times, while `insert` only once. With **libc++**, there is only one allocation with `emplace` as well; it seems there is some optimization that copies/moves keys<sup>*</sup>. I got the same outcome with **Microsoft STL**, so it actually seems that there is some missing optimization in libstdc++. However, the whole problem may not be related only to standard containers. For instance, `concurrent_unordered_map` from Intel/oneAPI TBB behaves the same as libstdc++ in this regard.

---

<sup>*</sup>Note that this optimization cannot be applied in cases where keys are both *non-copyable* and *non-movable*. In this live demo, we have 10 allocations even with `emplace` and libc++: https://godbolt.org/z/1b6b331qf. (Of course, with non-copyable and non-movable keys, we cannot use `insert` nor `try_emplace`, so then there is no other option.)

Answer (score -2):

In terms of functionality or output, they are both same.

For both large memory, object emplace is memory-optimized which don't use copy constructors

For simple detailed explanation
https://medium.com/@sandywits/all-about-emplace-in-c-71fd15e06e44

Comment: Emplace is not memory-optimized only for both large memory, it's why i downvoted.