# What is wrong in replacing a m[nums[i]]=i with a m.insert() function in hash map, where m is the name of the hash map

Tags: c++, hashtable

This is a leetcode question: [219. Contains Duplicate II](https://leetcode.com/problems/contains-duplicate-ii/)

I used the `insert` function for hash map. Can someone please tell me what is wrong with the first code?

```
//wrong solution
class Solution {
public:
   bool containsNearbyDuplicate(vector<int>& nums, int k) {
       unordered_map<int,int>m;
       int n=nums.size();
       for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
          if(m.find(nums[i])!=m.end() && abs(i-m[nums[i]]) <=k) return true;
          m.insert(pair<int,int>(nums[i],i));                                      //this is the faulty part
       }
       return false;
   }
};
```

```
//Right 
class Solution {
public:
    bool containsNearbyDuplicate(vector<int>& nums, int k) {
        unordered_map<int,int>m;
        int n=nums.size();
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
           if(m.find(nums[i])!=m.end() && abs(i-m[nums[i]]) <=k) return true;
           m[nums[i]]=i; 
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [insert vs emplace vs operator\[\] in c++ map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17172080/insert-vs-emplace-vs-operator-in-c-map)

Answer (score 2):

The `std::map` and `std::unordered_map` types have slightly unusual behavior for their `insert` functions. Specifically, if you use `insert` to add a key/value pair to the map, and the key already existed in the map, the `insert` operation doesn't actually add anything. Instead, it'll hand back an iterator to the element that was already there. Therefore, your first version of the code doesn't actually do what it looks like it does, since the `insert` call won't change the existing value.

On the other hand, using `operator[]` (the square brackets) doesn't do this. Selecting a key with `operator[]` either inserts a key/value pair and then returns a reference to the value, or returns a reference to the existing value. That's why the second version does work - it'll replace existing values with new ones when needed.